# How to pass a value in a return function as an argument on another function, use it in and then call it appropriately C++?

Tags: c++, function, arguments, return

I would like to know how to pass a return function to another function as an argument so that I can use its value.

Example:

```
int childFunction(int a, int b)
{
    int c;
    c = a + b;
    return c;
}

void motherFunction(int d, int (childFunction)(int a, int b))
{
    //some operation example
}
```

Thank you

Comment: You want to call the passed function pointer argument in `motherFunction`? What problems do you have with it now? Just call it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Pointer to function

Use `*` to make a pointer to a function:

```
void motherFunction(int d, int (*f)(int, int))
{
    int y = f(1, 2);
}
...

motherFunction(100, childFunction);
```

### std::function[<sup>1</sup>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)

```
void motherFunction(int d, const std::function<int(int,int)> &f)
{
    int y = f(1, 2);
}
...

motherFunction(100, childFunction);
```

### Template based

```
template <typename F>
void motherFunction(int d, const F &f)
{
    int y = f(1, 2);
}
...

motherFunction(100, childFunction);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare the `childFunction` parameter as a function pointer.

```
void motherFunction(int d, int (*func)(int, int))
{
    func(d, 0);
}


int childFunction(int a, int b)
{
    int c;
    c = a + b;
    return c;
}

int main()
{
    motherFunction(1, childFunction);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Pay particular attention to the additions M.M. made to his answer as they are a much more flexible set of solutions. You will find them very handy in the future I'm sure.